# Get image url in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I need to get the url of the image, i don't need the image itself i just need url. But i can't get it to work.

Here's the site: https://www.bauhaus.com.tr/hirdavat-hirdavat-urunleri-menteseler-mobilya-menteseleri/adilon-karyola-demiri-61185746

I have no experience in coding, so if there's an easier way please share it.
Here's the code:

```
Dim i, sonsat As Integer
Dim url As String
Dim XMLreq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLdoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

sonsat = Sheets("Sayfa1").Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To sonsat
On Error Resume Next

url = Sheets("Sayfa1").Range("A" & i)

XMLreq.Open "GET", url, False
XMLreq.send


If XMLreq.Status <> 200 Then

MsgBox "Sayfaya Ulaşılamadı"
Exit Sub

End If

HTMLdoc.body.innerHTML = XMLreq.responseText


Sheets("Sayfa1").Range("C" & i) = HTMLdoc.getElementsByClassName("title")(0).innerText
Sheets("Sayfa1").Range("B" & i) = HTMLdoc.getElementsByClassName("title sub")(0).innerText
Sheets("Sayfa1").Range("D" & i) = HTMLdoc.getElementsByClassName("proAttr sku")(0).innerText
Sheets("Sayfa1").Range("E" & i) = HTMLdoc.getElementsByclassName("item")(391).innerText



Next



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is about right, but it turns out the image is inserted after page load, probably by a JavaScript component. So when you get the document, it does not contain the image lightbox.

However, the image is referenced in the page metadata as

```html
<html>
  <head>
    ...
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://...">
    ...
  </head>
...
</html>
```

So you can pull it from there.

Also some advice about clean coding:

1. As you're running in a loop, the HTML document and XML HTTP Request objects would better be created each time (put `New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60` and `New MSHTML.HTMLDocument` inside the loop)
2. `HTMLDocument` should be closed after use

So here's a piece of code very close to your final requirements (I just changed the loop so I didn't have to re-make your Excel Workbook on my side:

```vb
Sub testHtml()

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim url As String
    Dim XMLreq As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLdoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim els As Variant 'DispHTMLElementCollection
    Dim meta As MSHTML.HTMLMetaElement
    
    'Replace following loop with your own (looping over worksheet column)
    For i = 1 To 3
        
        'You should actually read this url from your worksheet
        url = "https://www.bauhaus.com.tr/hirdavat-hirdavat-urunleri-menteseler-mobilya-menteseleri/adilon-karyola-demiri-61185746"
        
        Set XMLreq = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
        XMLreq.Open "GET", url, False
        XMLreq.send
    
        If XMLreq.Status <> 200 Then
            MsgBox "Error!"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set HTMLdoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        HTMLdoc.body.innerHTML = XMLreq.responseText
        
        Set els = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("meta")
        'Debug.Print els.Length
        For j = 0 To els.Length - 1
            Set meta = els(j)
            'Debug.Print meta.outerHTML
            If meta.getAttribute("property") = "og:image" Then
                Debug.Print meta.Content 'Output to Execution Window
                'You should output to your WorkSheet instead
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        
        HTMLdoc.Close
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

And final note: to see the ouput of `Debug.Print`, use the Execution Window in VBA

Comment: Thanks for the reply but when i run your code it's just blank. Do i need to activate something from references? And i paste url to the A column so its not needed in the code itself am i right ?

Comment: My code is showing you how to get the URL you needed from a static URL. It outputs it into the execution window. It does it in a pointless loop just to check if repeating everything works (as you need to do it for a bunch of rows). Now it will be up to you to refactor it to your needs: read the input URLs from your worksheet and output back to it, but you had this part correct already